# Properties of a subgroup of a group $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p \geq 5$ be a prime. Thhen which one of the followings are true.

1) $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ has atleast five subgroup of order p.

2) Every subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ is of the form$H_1 \times H_1$ , wher $H_1 ,H_2$ are subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$.

3)Every subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ is an ideal of the ring $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$.

4) The ring $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ is a field.

Cleary  4) option is not true because $(0,1) (1,0) = (0,0)$ , so $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ is not an integeral domain. I think 2) is true , but how.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following subgroup: $H:=\{(a,a) | a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \}$. It is not an ideal indeed $(2,2) \cdot (3,2) \not\in H$. And neither is it of the form $H_1 \times H_2$. Since you already gave a counterexample for the fourth alternative, we are  done.

Answer (score 2):

(1) is true.  Consider any element $x(k,n) = (nk\pmod p) \times k$ with $0\leq n<p$ and $k\neq 0\pmod p) $. It is easy to see that $x(k,n)$ gnerates a cyclic subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p$.  It is also easy to show that the group generated by  $x(k,m)$ does not contain $x(k,n)$. Thus there are $p$ distinct subgroups of this form.

(2) is false. Consider the subgroup $\{ k \times k\}$ with $0\leq k<p$. This is not of the form $H_1 \times H_2$.

You've got the answer for (4), and I don't know about (3).

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Comment: +1  @ Mark Fischler,,im not getting ur optiion 1) answer  that if i take k=1, and n=0,and x= 1,,,i can not able to think ,,,,how it is possible

Comment: @Mark Fischer can you please elaborate your reasoning of (2) nd  option?